# Can you use ‘is it’ in question form?

Tags: questions

Is the following sentence acceptable?

> Is it any way possible to change this?

I know that “Is there” is the popular way to say this, but is “Is it” incorrect?

Comment: IMO, it would be correct if written as _Is it, **anyway,** possible to change this?_ Anyway is an adverb here, something like _in any case_ .....BUT _Is there **any** way to change this?_

Answer (score 1):

The underlying phrase is "it is possible".

So "Is it in any way possible to ...?" is normal. (I would not omit "in", but I think some people would in speech).

"There is" requires a noun phrase, eg "there is a way". So "Is there any possible way to ... ?"